# How to update Comment post meta through an Ajax call

Tags: ajax, comments, post-meta

I want to develop a plugin that adds one or more metadata terms to the comments. I can do this by using the `add_comment_meta` function, and I can display it in the `edit-comments.php` page by using the `comment_status_links` and `pre_get_comments` hooks. The process I followed is similar to the one detailed here:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/editing-comment-meta-in-edit-comment-admin-panel

To clarify, at the top it now shows, for example:

```
All | Pending (10) | Approved (100) | Spam (0) | Trash (0) | MY METADATA (5)
```

Now, my issue is with the Ajax update of the comments count. For example, if a comment that is approved is then marked as spam, the number of approved comments, 100, is updated automatically to 99, and the number of spam comments increases from 0 to 1. However, the number of My Metadata does not change, and remains at 5 until I refresh the page; then, it updates to 4, which is what I want.

How can I include my metadata feature in the Ajax update, so the user does not need to refresh the page to see the correct number? I think I need to use a script similar to `wp-admin/js/edit-comments.js`, but would rather avoid using a whole different Ajax call, which would place somewhat redundant code there given the complex logic used already in the `edit-comments.js` script.

Any feedback is appreciated! Thanks your help!

Comment: Those numbers don't update on their own, it requires a page refresh. When you spam something and it updates the numbers, that's just javascript updating it on the page for you, afterall if you just clicked spam on a comment it already knows the spam count has gone up by one, so it doesn't wait for the server and adds 1 to the number